# Keystone JS/JS Mongo Query , How to query data using URLSearchParams as Keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, keystonejs

Wanted to make a dynamic query where in it would return data based on the urlSearchParams data that matches the result. It should return the data from the database where Key and values that matches from urlSearchParams like all the Year which is 2019 and 2018 so on and so forth.

## This is the part where i am having trouble in making so , in making this

dynamic based on the urlSearchParams , How can we make it that it will query and return the data that matches in the urlSearchParams ( { 'Year' => '2019,2018', 'Make' => 'Acura,BMW' })

```
q.where(urlSearchParams key should be here).in([urlSearchParams]);
```

## URL SEARCH PARAM

```
{ 'Year' => '2019,2018', 'Make' => 'Acura,BMW' }
```

## Query Code

```
view.on('init', function (next) {

        var q = keystone.list('Post').paginate({
            page: req.query.page || 1,
            perPage: 2,
            maxPages: 2,
            filters: {
                state: 'published', 
            },
        })
            .sort('-publishedDate')
            .populate('author categories');

        if (locals.data.category) {

            //Where key is in urlSearchParams for example based on this searchparams
            { 'Year' => '2019,2018', 'Make' => 'Acura,BMW' }
            It should return the data from the database where Key and values that matches from urlSearchParams
            like all the Year which is 2019 and 2018 so on and so forth
            q.where('Key Here ').in([urlSearchParams]);
        }

        q.exec(function (err, results) {
            locals.data.posts = results;

            next(err);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Please share sample data and query that you wrote, so that devs can refactor that.

Comment: Query Code
 that is the sample query